# ExpressionChangedAfterChecked on enter but not click

Tags: angular, angular7

In my angular 7 application I'm getting this error if I press the enter key while in the input field, but not if I click on the search button:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'igx-input-group--focused: true'. Current value: 'igx-input-group--focused: false'.

The code triggering it looks like this:

```html
<igx-input-group>
    <label igxLabel for="search">Asset Search</label>
    <input #search igxInput type="text" class="form-control" id="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText"
           required (keyup.enter)="onSearchPressed()">
    <igx-hint>Search by S/N, Etag, barcode or RFID</igx-hint>
</igx-input-group>

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSearchPressed()" [disabled]="searchButtonDisabled">
    Search
</button>
```

As you can see, both pressing enter and clicking the button call the `onSearchPressed()` method.  I'm not understanding why the one causes the error but the other doesn't.

Comment: It seems that pressing `enter` triggers `onSearchPressed()` two times. One from button `click` (as it might be in focus) and another from `keyup,enter`. so it throwing this error because the value is changed while 1 cycle of `ChangeDetection` completes

Comment: It's only being called on time based on my debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but this error is most likely due to the `igxInput` reacting to the `enter` press as well. Since the `igxInput` directive is bound to the `<input>` tag, it reacts to the enter, but not to the click on the `<button>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your method in setTimeout, after that it will run it own changedetection and this error will go.

Hope that helped

Comment: Seems like a hack?  I'll definitely try it though if it gets me past for now!

Answer (score 0):

For me, moving certain code that depends on query string "i.e. ActivatedRoute" from ngOnInit() to constructor() resolved the problem.
I'm not sure why, but this might help someone.